# Batch messaging tracking and monitoring

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, batch-processing

I receive a multiple files(huge nos) of 100,000 records and need to be processed with 3 hours.

Each record needs to be processed by multiple(4) tasks and atlast all records from 1 file are merged together and processed.

Now, I'm planning to use REDIS or RABBIT-MQ as my queuing system.

ie:-

```
file1

batch-1 
    record-1
    record-2

batch-2
    record-3
    record-4
```

How can I track all the records of file1 at last ie; I need a correlation id for my different batches.

1.Is there a preferred architecture to implement this?
2.How can I create a correlation id for all my messages?

I'm very new to queuing system, so inputs would be very useful.

Comment: Not understanding why you tagged this with batch-file. I don't see how that fits into your question.

Comment: Do any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rabbitmq+correlation+id